# ObservableMap with extractor for values?

Tags: java, javafx, observable

Short: I am looking for a way to update contents of `ListView` based on changes made to `Map` and **values inside** the map.

Situation:

There is "source" `LinkedHashMap<String, Data>` on logical side of application.

On GUI part there is a ListView such as:

```
// Gui list.
ListView<Data> list = new ListView<>();

// Observable map wrapping logical map
ObservableMap<String, Data> items = FXCollections.observableMap(logic.getLogicalMap());
// This listener will cause gui list to also change logical list
items.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, Data>) change ->
{
    list.getItems().removeAll(change.getValueRemoved());
    if (change.wasAdded())
    {
        list.getItems().add(change.getValueAdded());
    }
});
// Show values of map in ListView.
list.getItems().setAll(items.values());

list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Data>, ListCell<Data>>()
{
    @Override
    public ListCell<Data> call(ListView<Data> list)
    {
        return new DataCell();
    }
});
// Basically cells that update when map is updated.
private static class DataCell extends ListCell<Data>
{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Data item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item != null)
        {
            this.setText(item.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            this.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now: Everything is cool until I want cells to display changes made to `Data` contained in `Map#values()`.

I ran into Extractors, but apparently they are only for ObservableLists.
So now: How do I notify ObservableMap (which then notifies ListView) of updates happening on "cellular" (values) level?

Comment: How does your `Data` class look like? It needs to provide something like a property or at least functionality to register listeners to be able to react from outside to changes which happen inside the data.

Comment: Till about 10min after posting this question it was POJO. This is why my DataCell#updateItem is using plain item.toString().
It was this way because till now Data was also immutable. Since now it will be receiving "status updates" we can consider it as JavaBean - so all data held there will be JavaFX Properties.
Note: I am now exploring option of binding cell data to property of Data bean. For the purpose of solving this problem structure of Data can be basically "any" - as long as it will help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refractoring `Data` to be JavaBean (was POJO) and using (in `DataCell#updateItem`):

```
this.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(item.propertyOne(), " / ", item.propertyTwo()));
```

Solves my problems.

Comment: Also note that instead of using a binding in the `updateItem()` method, you can do `list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(d -> new Observable[] {d.propertyOne(), d.propertyTwo()});`. Then just use the usual `setText(...)` in your cell's `updateItem` method. In other words, you don't need the extractor on the map; it's enough to have it just on the list. Since the list contains the same objects as the map, it will be observing the correct properties and firing updates if they change.

Comment: Note that with your listener you make the items behave like a "multiset": the same value can be added for multiple times; removing any of those values from the map will remove the first one from the list. Furthermore if you add `null` as value, the item can be removed by adding a new item to the list (this would also lead to a NPE in `updateItem`).